# Do problem constraints change the time complexity of algorithms?

Tags: algorithm, big-o

Let's say that the algorithm involves iterating through a string character by character.

If I know for sure that the length of the string is less than, say, 15 characters, will the time complexity be O(1) or will it remain as O(n)?

Comment: Is `n` the number of characters?

Comment: If you know the length of the string is less than 15 characters then what do you mean by time complexity?

Comment: Are you only interested in size limits on `n` (or `m` for problems with multiple dimensions of complexity)?  Or are you considering the more general case like "already sorted" or "at most 4 elements in wrong positions"?  Or "all unique" for a list of integers that you want to add to a hash table?

Comment: Also, a super-tiny size limit like 15 (as small as one vector register on modern CPUs) feels very different from a limit like 1024.  In practice if you knew that limit existed, you might use a different algorithm, depending on what you were doing to each character, but that's different from considering the time complexity of an existing algorithm that you don't change to take advantage.

Answer (score 27):

There are two aspects to this question - the core of the question is, *can* problem constraints change the asymptotic complexity of an algorithm? The answer to that is **yes**. But then you give an example of a constraint (strings limited to 15 characters) where the answer is: **the question doesn't make sense**. A lot of the other answers here are misleading because they address only the second aspect but try to reach a conclusion about the first one.

Formally, the asymptotic complexity of an algorithm is measured by considering a set of inputs where the input sizes (i.e. what we call *n*) are unbounded. The reason *n* must be unbounded is because the definition of asymptotic complexity is a statement like *"there is some n<sub>0</sub> such that for all n ≥ n<sub>0</sub>, ..."*, so if the set doesn't contain any inputs of size *n* ≥ *n*<sub>0</sub> then this statement is [vacuous](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vacuous_truth).

Since algorithms can have different running times depending on *which* inputs of each size we consider, we often distinguish between "average", "worst case" and "best case" time complexity. Take for example [insertion sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Insertion_sort):

- In the average case, insertion sort has to compare the current element with half of the elements in the sorted portion of the array, so the algorithm does about *n*<sup>2</sup>/4 comparisons.
- In the worst case, when the array is in descending order, insertion sort has to compare the current element with every element in the sorted portion (because it's less than all of them), so the algorithm does about *n*<sup>2</sup>/2 comparisons.
- In the best case, when the array is in ascending order, insertion sort only has to compare the current element with the largest element in the sorted portion, so the algorithm does about *n* comparisons.

However, now suppose we add the constraint that the input array is always in ascending order except for its smallest element:

- Now the average case does about 3*n*/2 comparisons,
- The worst case does about 2*n* comparisons,
- And the best case does about *n* comparisons.

Note that it's *the same algorithm*, insertion sort, but because we're considering a different set of inputs where the algorithm has different performance characteristics, we end up with a different time complexity for the average case *because we're taking an average over a different set*, and similarly we get a different time complexity for the worst case *because we're choosing the worst inputs from a different set*. Hence, yes, adding a problem constraint can change the time complexity even if the algorithm itself is not changed.

However, now let's consider your example of an algorithm which iterates over each character in a string, with the added constraint that the string's length is at most 15 characters. Here, it does not make sense to talk about the asymptotic complexity, because the input sizes *n* in your set are not unbounded. This particular set of inputs is not valid for doing such an analysis with.

Comment: Among all the answers that were posted, this is the only one that makes sense.

Comment: To be fair, if the size upper bound is quite large, you can often be confident it's larger than the critical size n0.  e.g. for sorting arrays where the size is an unsigned 32-bit integer, 2^32-1 elements is plenty to distinguish the average case for O(n^2) Insertion Sort from the average case for any O(n log n) algorithm.  That's what makes it still relevant to talk about big-O complexity for that case, but less so for a tiny size like 15 where practical constant factors are likely to dominate when comparing to an algorithm with a different complexity for unbounded inputs.

Comment: OTOH, you could say that a big-O analysis is only of the abstract algorithm, not of any concrete implementation on a finite machine, or set of inputs you run it with.  And choosing to run a finite implementation of it may or may not make conclusions based on big-O meaningless or wrong even for the maximum supported size.  That's normally not the case for reasonable size limits, especially on 32 and 64-bit computers, but can be for vastly shorter size limits like 15 elements (4-bit).  In that case, alternative algorithms may well be faster.

Comment: @PeterCordes I think there is a misunderstanding here - there is no "critical" n_0, the statement is that *there exists* an n_0 but not that it is unique. So if I can pick an n_0 larger than any n in the input set, the statement is vacuously true and we would be able to formally prove that the algorithm has any asymptotic complexity you want - not just in big O notation but also big omega, big theta or any other asymptotic notation such as the relation `f ~ g`.

Comment: Additionally, while it's appealing to imagine that we might be able to analyse the complexity of an algorithm without reference to what its inputs are, I am not aware of any formal definition that does not depend on choosing a set of inputs with unbounded *n*. It seems difficult and not very useful to try to make such a definition. From another perspective, the set of possible inputs is part of the abstract specification of the algorithm, independent of the fact that on real physical computers there is a much more limited set of physically possible inputs.

Comment: What it boils down to is that an algorithm as a set of instructions only gives you a function like *"T(X) = number of steps it takes to compute the algorithm on the input X"*, but to do asymptotic analysis you want a function like *"T(n) = number of steps it takes to compute the algorithm on an input of size n"*. To T(X) into T(n) we need some way of transforming a number *n* into an input of size *n* (or a set of such inputs to take an average or extremum from), and then if your function T(n) is not defined for infinitely many *n*, it has no asymptotic behaviour at all.

Comment: If you're comparing two algorithms of different complexity classes, you could define a "critical n_0" as the size above which the slower complexity class algorithm always runs slower in practice.  I realize this is not the usual formal definition; it's an attempt to adapt things to make sense with a large but finite n.

Comment: As for asymptotic behaviour, with finite n you could instead look at the trend towards the upper limit of the range of allowed n.  e.g. an O(n^2) algorithm that also has some O(n log n) work which are dominated by the n^2 term as n tends toward infinity, so can be dropped from the Big-O complexity.  In most cases a 32 or 64-bit `n` is large enough for the n^2 part of the complexity to dominate, and fit a scale * n^2 curve fairly well.  Of course, you could maybe invent cases where this doesn't work, and knowing that it worked right relies on looking at the abstract algo for infinite n.

Comment: I think we'd both agree that it makes sense to call a concrete implementation of InsertionSort for an integer array an O(n^2) algorithm.  But you're saying we can only reach that conclusion by looking at the abstract algorithm, not the concrete implementation that has a size limit.  That's a reasonable argument.  A size limit like 15 instead of 2^31-1 feels different to me for most algorithms, and I guess I want to come up with some way to distinguish those.  Maybe the way I'm trying to argue for isn't a good way :P

Comment: @PeterCordes All of that is reasonable and you make some good points. Definitely the way programmers think about big O notation in practice is quite different in some ways to how one must think about it formally (especially the concept of a "big enough n for it to matter", which is very informal but also a useful concept for intuition and practice). And I certainly use the informal ideas often myself. What I'd say is that there is a difference between thinking informally as an expert who *would* be able to formalise their ideas if necessary, and thinking informally as a novice because you ...

Comment: ... haven't yet grasped how to think formally about it. At least here, I chose to base my answer more on the formal definition because I think the question is based on informal thinking of the second kind. Regarding insertion sort, I would indeed call a concrete implementation O(n^2) despite the limits of the computer's word size, memory capacity and so on. In my mind, the difference between those limits and "the string length is at most 15" is not the magnitude of the numbers, but that the first is imposed by practical considerations while the second is part of the problem specification.

Answer (score 12):

In the mathematical sense, yes. Big-O notation describes the behavior of an algorithm in the limit, and if you have a fixed upper bound on the input size, that implies it has a maximum constant complexity.

That said, context is important. All computers have a realistic limit to the amount of input they can accept (a technical upper bound). Just because nothing in the world can store a yottabyte of data doesn't mean saying every algorithm is `O(1)` is useful! It's about applying the mathematics in a way that makes sense for the situation.

Here are two contexts for your example, one where it makes sense to call it `O(1)`, and one where it does not.

1. "I decided I won't put strings of length more than 15 into my program, therefore it is `O(1)`". This is not a super useful interpretation of the runtime. The actual time is still strongly tied to the size of the string; a string of size 1 will run much faster than one of size 15 even if there is technically a constant bound. In other words, *within* the constraints of your problem there is still a strong correlation to `n`.
2. "My algorithm will process a list of `n` strings, each with maximum size 15". Here we have a different story; the runtime is dominated by having to run through the list! There's a point where `n` is so large that the time to process a single string doesn't change the correlation. Now it makes sense to consider the time to process a single string `O(1)`, and therefore the time to process the whole list `O(n)`

That said, Big-O notation doesn't have to only use one variable! There are problems where upper bounds are intrinsic to the algorithm, but you wouldn't put a bound on the input arbitrarily. Instead, you can describe each dimension of your input as a different variable:

```
n = list length
s = maximum string length
=> O(n*s)
```

Comment: *a string of size 1 will run much faster than one of size 15* - Will it always, though?  In a real use-case where data is cold in cache, most of the time cost may come from the cache miss, with only a small amount scaling with problem size.  Also, 15 is absolutely tiny in terms of practical implementations; the whole string will always fit in two 64-bit registers.  Depending what you're doing with the string, it might be best to use a non-looping implementation that does a fixed amount of work.  (Although that optimization would be changing the algorithm to one with different complexity.)

Comment: @PeterCordes You're correct, but the discussion is more about standard Big-O analysis. I felt that worrying about caching/vector instructions/other computational complexities wasn't relevant to what the OP was trying to get at. The example would be better if the string was bounded to some relatively-large number where the CPU-time was more correlated to the string size.

Comment: But if you put a tiny limit on `n`, you're far away from standard Big-O analysis.  As kaya3 argues, the *formal* definitions rely on unbounded sizes, although usually a 32-bit integer can hold a large enough size that big-O factors dominate constant factors when comparing two algorithms.  But not a 4-bit integer size.

Answer (score 11):

It depends.

If your algorithm's requirements would grow if larger inputs were provided, then the *algorithmic complexity* can (and should) be evaluated independently of the inputs. So iterating over all the elements of a list, array, string, etc., is `O(n)` in relation to the length of the input.

If your algorithm is tied to the limited input size, then that fact becomes part of your algorithmic complexity. For example, maybe your algorithm only iterates over the first 15 characters of the input string, regardless of how long it is. Or maybe your business case simply indicates that a larger input would be an indication of a bug in the calling code, so you opt to immediately exit with an error whenever the input size is larger than a fixed number. In those cases, the algorithm will have constant requirements as the input length tends toward very large numbers.

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation)

> Big O notation is a mathematical notation that describes the limiting behavior of a function when the argument tends towards a particular value or infinity.
> ...
> In computer science, big O notation is used to classify algorithms according to how their run time or space requirements grow as the input size grows.

In practice, almost all inputs have limits: you cannot input a number larger than what's representable by the numeric type, or a string that's larger than the available memory space. So it would be silly to say that any limits change an algorithm's asymptotic complexity. You could, in theory, use 15 as your *asymptote* (or "particular value"), and therefore use Big-O notation to define how an algorithm grows as the input approaches that size. There are *some* algorithms with such terrible complexity (or some execution environments with limited-enough resources) that this would be meaningful.

But if your argument (string length) does not tend toward a large enough value for some aspect of your algorithm's complexity to define the growth of its resource requirements, it's arguably not appropriate to use asymptotic notation at all.

Answer (score 1):

### NO!

The time complexity of an algorithm is independent of program constraints. Here is (a simple) way of thinking about it:

> Say your algorithm iterates over the string and appends all consonants to a list.
>
> Now, for iteration time complexity is O(n). This means that the time taken will increase roughly in proportion to the increase in the length of the string. (Time itself though would vary depending on the time taken by the if statement and [Branch Prediction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Branch_predictor))

**The fact that you know that the string is between 1 and 15 characters long will not change how the program runs, it merely tells you what to expect.**

For example, knowing that your values are going to be less than 65000 you could store them in a 16-bit integer and not worry about [Integer overflow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_overflow).

Comment: I think you meant 32,000 or 65,000 instead of 100,000.

Comment: ... or 65,536... ;-)

Comment: @MarkRansom yes, I chaned it from 32bit to 16bit but forgot to change 100000

Comment: This is not generally true; for example, the time complexity of insertion sort is O(n^2), but if you know the list is already in order then the time complexity is O(n), even though it is the same algorithm.

Comment: @kaya3 You are absolutely right. I just gave the answer for the given context.(MAX_SIZE of a string and interation over it.)

Comment: @kaya3 I will admit, your answer is quite a fair bit better than mine though,

Answer (score 0):

> Do problem constraints change the time complexity of algorithms?

No.

> If I know for sure that the length of the string is less than, say, 15 characters ..."

We already know the length of the string is less than `SIZE_MAX`.  Knowing an upper fixed bound for string length does not make the the time complexity O(1).

Time complexity remains O(n).

Comment: What is `SIZE_MAX`?

Comment: @Bergi In C, `SIZE_MAX` is the maximum of type `size_t` and the maximum array index.  A string's length, is always less than `SIZE_MAX`.  In general, all computer languages impose an upper bound.  The point is that have some upper bound, be it SIZE_MAX or 15, does not change O().

Comment: Not all languages do, but all implementations do :-)

Answer (score 0):

A fundamental requirement of big-O notation is that parameters do not have an upper limit.  Suppose performing an operation on `N` elements takes a time precisely equal to `3E24*N*N*N / (1E24+N*N*N)` microseconds.  For small values of `N`, the execution time would be proportional to `N^3`, but as `N` gets larger the `N^3` term in the denominator would start to play an increasing role in the computation.

If `N` is `1`, the time would be 3 microseconds.
If `N` is `1E3`, the time would be about 3E33/1E24, i.e. 3.0E9.
If `N` is `1E6`, the time would be about 3E42/1E24, i.e. 3.0E18
If `N` is `1E7`, the time would be 3E45/1.001E24, i.e. ~2.997E21
If `N` is `1E8`, the time would be about 3E48/2E24, i.e. 1.5E24
If `N` is `1E9`, the time would be 3E51/1.001E27, i.e. ~2.997E24
If `N` is `1E10`, the time would be about 3E54/1.000001E30, i.e. 2.999997E24

As `N` gets bigger, the time would continue to grow, but no matter how big `N` gets the time would always be less than 3.000E24 seconds.  Thus, the time required for this algorithm would be `O(1)` because one could specify a constant `k` such that the time necessary to perform the computation with size `N` would be less than `k`.

For any practical value of `N`, the time required would be proportional to `N^3`, but from an `O(N)` standpoint the worst-case time requirement is constant.  The fact that the time changes rapidly in response to small values of `N` is irrelevant to the "big picture" behaviour, which is what big-O notation measures.

Answer (score 0):

Big-O measures the complexity of algorithms, not of code. It means Big-O does not know the physical limitations of computers. A Big-O measure today will be the same in 1 million years when computers, and programmers alike, have evolved beyond recognition.

So restrictions imposed by today's computers are irrelevant for Big-O. Even though any loop is finite in code, that need not be the case in algorithmic terms. The loop may be finite or infinite. It is up to the programmer/Big-O analyst to decide. Only s/he knows which algorithm the code intends to implement. If the number of loop iterations is finite, the loop has a Big-O complexity of O(1) because there is no asymptotic growth with N. If, on the other hand, the number of loop iterations is infinite, the Big-O complexity is O(N) because there is an asymptotic growth with N.

The above is straight from the definition of Big-O complexity. There are no ifs or buts. The way the OP describes the loop makes it O(1).

Answer (score 0):

It will be **O(1)** i.e. constant.

This is because for calculating time complexity or worst-case time complexity (to be precise), we think of the input as a huge chunk of data and the length of this data is assumed to be **n**.

Let us say, we do some maximum work **C** on each part of this input data, which we will consider as a constant.
In order to get the worst-case time complexity, we need to loop through each part of the input data i.e. we need to loop **n** times.
So, the time complexity will be:
**`n x C`**.

Since you fixed **n** to be less than 15 characters, **n** can also be assumed as a constant number.
Hence in this case:
**`n = constant`** and,
**`(maximum constant work done) = C = constant`**
So time complexity is **n x C = constant x constant = constant** i.e. **O(1)**

## Edit

The reason why I have said ***`n = constant`*** and ***`C = constant`*** for this case, is because the time difference for doing calculations for smaller `n` will become so insignificant (compared to **n** being a very large number) for modern computers that we can assume it to be constant.

Otherwise, every function ever build will take some time, and we can't say things like:
*lookup time is constant for hashmaps*

Comment: "*time complexity or worst case time complexity (to be precise)*" - I would think generic term usually refers to the average time complexity

Comment: Wrong. It would be O(n) since the string can also be one character. If calling with one character will do one computation, and 15 will do 15 computations, it will be 15 (n) times more. The fact that it is limited to 15 only means that it will cap out at n=15.